# iOS webkit/webview pushing and distorting content

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview, mobile-safari

I have hit a roadblock here that I hope someone will be able to help me with.

I am designing a webview for an app (a support ticket submission form), and some pretty screwy things are happening. Below is what the form looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpJa1.png

And when I go ahead and click on the "how can we help you" textarea it does this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpAuS.png

It just cuts off a bunch of my  element that contains the form!

Also, when I first click into the textarea, I am unable to actually type until I click out and click back in again...

Something else that is weird? It works perfectly fine on mobile safari! Just not in this web-view!

Does anyone know what would be causing this to happen with my code? I can provide snippets of whatever you need, I'd really appreciate it!!

Comment: You wil have to post the relevant code, else there is very lttle chance that someone can help you.

Comment: Heres a paste of my form code that is inside of an iFrame:
http://pastebin.com/q9FvRuX5

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by detecting for a focus event using jQuery, and then blurring the field only one time, then the user just has to manually enter into the input. All is good!

```
var disabled = false;
    $("#ticketSubmissionForm").contents().find("input[data-reactid='.5.1.0.1:1.1.0.1']").focus(function() {
if(disabled == false){
    this.blur();
    disabled = true;
}

});
```